# TableViewCell to ViewController - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, viewcontroller

I tried many ways but still can't go to another `ViewController`. This is my storyboard.
[image: imgStoryboard]

and This is my code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? HistoryMainTableViewCell {
        listItems.sort() { $0.seq > $1.seq }
        let history = listItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.setValue(history: history)

        return cell
    } else {
        return HistoryMainTableViewCell()
    }
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "vcProductHistory" {
        if let productHistoryPage = segue.destination as? HistoryProductViewController {
            if let IndexPath = tableViewHistory.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let historyArray = listItems[IndexPath.row]
                productHistoryPage.history = historyArray
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add Segue from `HistoryMainTableViewCell` to `HistoryProductViewController`?

Comment: are you adding the performSegue function where the event occurs to let the VC know to start doing the segue?

Comment: @lee5783 I added already

Comment: @PanPipatpunlop: Have you tried to use TableViewDelegate to handle Cell Selected instead?

Comment: **Do not** use a type (starting with an uppercase letter) as a variable name. `IndexPath` is a type in Swift 3. Consider the naming convention that variable names start always with a **lower**case letter.

Comment: @JustinM I drag segua line from TableViewCell and use function prepare to send value with segue

Comment: @vadian I changed it and still got same problem

Comment: dragging the line tells your vc about the segue, preparing for segue tells your vc what do when the segue is triggered, but you still need to let your vc know when it should perform the segue. try what Joe said below.

Comment: probably you have problem setting storyboard segue identifier?

Comment: @JustinM I added already but still not working, wanna cry T T

Comment: @Joe I check it again and again. My storyboard segue identifier and perform segue identifier are same

Comment: how you connecting a segue .is from main view to targetVC...

Comment: @Joe yes, from main view to targetVC

Comment: does the `prepareForSegue` method gets called and where are you performing the `segue`?

Comment: You should connect segue from mainVC to targrtVC directly not to navigationController which embedded with targetVC..

Comment: @PanPipatpunlop Did you find a solution that works for you?

Comment: @d.felber yep, already

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:(**Untested Code**)

**Note:** Below code will trigger prepare segue. When, tableViewCell selected.Let me know the code works...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {

   // let indexPath = myTableView!.indexPathForSelectedRow
   // let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
   //sendSelectedData = (currentCell.textLabel?.text)! as String as NSString
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "vcProductHistory", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer to my initial comment: dragging the line from initial vc to destination vc tells your vc about the segue, preparing for segue tells your vc what do when the segue is triggered, but you still need to let your vc know when it should perform the segue. try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? HistoryMainTableViewCell else { return HistoryMainTableViewCell() }

    let history = listItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.setValue(history: history)

    return cell
  }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "vcProductHistory" {
        guard let productHistoryPage = segue.destination as? HistoryProductViewController, let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath else { return }

        let historyArray = listItems[indexPath.row]
        productHistoryPage.history = historyArray
            }
        }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {

      performSegue(withIdentifier: "vcProductHistory", sender: indexPath)
}
```

I think this is a little bit neater using the guard syntax. Also, it uses sender as the indexPath, not using tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.

Also, I noticed you have this in your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
listItems.sort() { $0.seq > $1.seq }
```

Your sorting your data source in cellForRowAtIndexPath. You can't do that there because that function gets called for each row individually. You need to do the sorting before that is called, somewhere like viewWillAppear. Also, to sort an array in place you need to remove the () after sort. try this.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)

   listItems.sort { $0.0.seq > $0.1.seq }
   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: are you getting any errors? did you try using print statements in didSelectRowAtIndexPath? Is everything showing up in table properly and when you select the row do you see the tint change to indicate it was selected? Use some print statements to figure out whats not getting called, if everything is, you must have connected the segue wrong or are using the wrong identifier

Comment: no error show. i print statement in didSelectRowAtIndexPath but nothing show but when i select the row I see the tint change

Comment: did you correctly assign your vc as the delegate as well as the data source? it sounds like your didSelectRow isn't getting called by delegate.

Comment: assign already but still same, do you want my project to check it? there's no error and link correctly but i don't know why it's not work

Comment: is it on github? if you send me a link I'll check it out

Comment: No, not on github. Here's a link >> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-8X6_xU9QvFdkFZWG9QR3ZlQmM ::::: username: user1, password: password1

Comment: How was it? do you have any solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should connect to UINavigationController , not to HistoryProductionViewController

Because your MainViewController's segue connected to Navigation Controller

I guess in func `prepareForSegue` `segue.identifier == "vcProductHistory"` it works but, `if let productHistoryPage = segue.destination as? HistoryProductViewController` not works

because your destination ViewController's class is NavigationController

you should call

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "vcProductHistory" {
        if let naviVC = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {
            if let productHistoryPage = naviVC.topViewController as? HistoryProductViewController {
                if let IndexPath = tableViewHistory.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                    let historyArray = listItems[IndexPath.row]
                    productHistoryPage.history = historyArray
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution - as you described it - should work.
The most work here can be done directly in the Storyboard.
Select the prototype cell in the `TableView`, drag the Segue to the `NavigationController` and select `presentModally`.
[image: Variant 1 Setup]

This should work without further magic.
When selecting the `TableViewCell` the `NavigationController` should be presented. There is also no code needed at this point (except for the population of the `TableView`).
If not - you maybe misconfigured your `TableView` by setting the selection to `No Selection`:

[image: Selection set to no selection?]

or you set `User Interaction Enabled` to false somewhere.

Comment: @PanPipatpunlop Hm this is strange. Can you provide a sample project containing the three ViewControllers? (Marked with "Main" and "Target ViewController")